# Vim command for inserting a character

Tags: vim, vi

I'm looking for the opposite of `x`. I want to insert just one character and stay in command mode.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You could map a key(-sequence) to a command sequence, f.e.:

```
:map <C-i> i_<Esc>r
```

Ctrl-i takes one character and returns afterwards.

To make it persistent, add the same line to the local or global vimrc file:

```
~/.vimrc
/etc/vim/vimrc
```

Comment: To put in a vimrc file one should leave out the `:`

Comment: I don't get it.. whether you do `i` {char} `Esc` or `CTRL`-`i` {char}, it's still three keystrokes.  I'd say if you are going to customize your setup, just make Esc more readily available, e.g. by mapping CapsLock to it.

Answer (score 1):

In some situations you can just use `r`. From `:help r`:

> Replace the character under the cursor
>   with {char}.

If you want more than one char, use `R`. (When used it enters in *Replace mode*. As usual, for more info, `:help Replace`).

Remember to run `vimtutor` at least once to learn some commands. The `r` command is used in Lesson 3.2.

Comment: op was blatantly talking about inserting, _not_ replacing. how did this get at least 2 upvotes?